# Why can't react show a section of my array, but it can show it whole?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to put in documente data from firebase's firestore databate, no errors, if i log the whole documente i can see that it has everything i want, but when i want to log only a part it's undefined, why is that?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import '../components/Inbox.css'
import Sidebar from "../components/sidebar"
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, setDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Inbox() {

  const {currentUser} = useAuth()
  const q = query(collection(db, 'mails'), where('recipient', '==', currentUser.email))
  const documente = useState([])
  
  async function emails() {

      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          documente.push({
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.data().title,
            sender: doc.data().sender
          })
          console.log(documente.title) //this logs undefined and console.log(documente) logs out all the information so i know it s there
        })

      }
      catch {
        console.log('no work')
      }

    }

  useEffect(() => {emails()}, [])
    
    return (
    <>
    <AuthProvider>
        <Sidebar />
        {console.log(documente)}
    </AuthProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default Inbox
```

I ve tried using other methods to store the documents but i havent been able to figure them out, this is the closest i ve been to being able to map the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the properties of an array using the dot notation, which only works for objects.  `documente` is an array and you are trying to access the `title` property which does not exist and it results in undefined.

```
async function emails() {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            documente.push({
                id: doc.id,
                title: doc.data().title,
                sender: doc.data().sender
            });
            console.log(documente[documente.length - 1].title)
        });
    } catch {
        console.log('no work')
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do i acces it

Comment: Added a code example. Though I suggest you to read about Javascript Arrays and Objects.

Answer (score 0):

first this is not how u use State Hook in react. useState hook returns current state and a function that updates it so u need to destructure it like this:

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState([]);
```

and use setDocument only when u try to change the state of the component.

```
async function emails() {

  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    setDocument(querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
       return { 
        id: doc.id,
        title: doc.data().title,
        sender: doc.data().sender
      }
      }))
  }
  catch {
    console.log('no work')
  }

}
```

And second u are trying to access a title property of an array! If u want for example the first document u need to do it like this.

```
console.log(document[0].title);
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand, but I tried to write it like this and it just goes into the catch clause

Comment: Hello i just test the code with a dummy json in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-glade-odoqsq?file=/src/App.js
and it works fine.
Can u log the error so i can see what's the problem u have?